# Google Play Games Services crashes briefly after loadPlayerCenteredScores

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm writing a game in android using Google Play Games Services. I want to get other players using GamesClient.[loadPlayerCenteredScores](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadPlayerCenteredScores%28com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29). The problem has to do with getting the profile image. I use [getScoreHolderIconImageUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#getScoreHolderIconImageUri%28%29) and fetch the URI with [ImageManager.loadImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html#loadImage%28com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener,%20android.net.Uri,%20int%29). My image loaded listener never gets called and games services stops working like a second after the call, the game continues normally (As if games services was disconnected) and  I don't get any error in the log whatsoever except for a warning.
 Here is the code:

```
public void PlayersLoader(){
    getMainActivity().getGamesClient().loadPlayerCenteredScores(
            new OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onLeaderboardScoresLoaded(int statusCode, LeaderboardBuffer leaderboard, LeaderboardScoreBuffer scores){
                    if(statusCode==0){
                        LeaderboardScore score;
                        String playerId=getMainActivity().getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getPlayerId();
                        ImageManager imMan=ImageManager.create(getContext());
                        for(int i=0;i<scores.getCount();i++){
                            score=scores.get(i);
                            String name;
                            if(score.getScoreHolder().getPlayerId().equals(playerId)){
                                name=getResources().getString(R.string.your_best);
                            }
                            else{
                                name=score.getScoreHolderDisplayName();
                            }
                            Uri imuri=score.getScoreHolderIconImageUri();
                            if(imuri!=null){
                                imMan.loadImage(new ImageLoaded(name),imuri);
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Finish");
                        scores.close();
                        leaderboard.close();
                    }
                }
            },getResources().getString(R.string.HighScores),LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
            LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_SOCIAL,10);
}

}
class ImageLoaded implements OnImageLoadedListener{
String mName;
public ImageLoaded(String name){
    mName=new String(name);

    System.out.println(mName);
            //This does get printed out (the names of the players)
}
@Override
public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable){

    System.out.println("imageLoaded"); //This never gets printed out

}
}
```

This is what I get in the log:

```
//Your Best
//Player 1 Name
//Player 2 Name
//Finished
//Games Services has stopped working dialog in phone, when I click OK, this warning shows:
//*** Unexpectedly disconnected. Severing remaining connections.
```

If I remove the ImageManager call and print out the names only, they get printed out correctly and nothing stops working.

I don't know what's happening, I'm desperate.

EDIT
Even if I comment this line:

`imMan.loadImage(new ImageLoaded(name),imuri);`

the error happens.
It is only when I remove this that it stops happening:

`Uri imuri=score.getScoreHolderIconImageUri();` 
It's so strange! Even if I do not do anything with `imuri`.

EDIT I posted the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=7). It seems it was a bug of Google Play Services. Sure they will fix it soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you're running into the same problem described in the [public bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=7). If so, a fix is inbound and things should be working again Real Soon Now[tm].

Comment: Yeah! I was actually the one that posted that Issue. I forgot to add it here after they answered. Thank you!